# Custom script injection

Tags: javascript, office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams

Can I inject custom JS in Microsoft Teams? When I tried injecting it says

```
Refused to load the script 'xxxxxxxxxx.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src *.protection.outlook.com 'nonce-yaXPKdhE1aa/JhA/PFsoyw==' 'report-sample' 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: *.office.net *.office365.us *.cms.rt.microsoft.com *.delve.office.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.onenote.com *.presence.skype.com *.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net *.trouter.io ajax.aspnetcdn.com amp.azure.net.
```

Of course, It's a genuine error. My question is that is there any ethical, legal way to inject even if it requires permission from the admin. In short, Is there any right way to do it?

Comment: Can you please describe more about the scenario?

Comment: In layman terms, I want to execute a javascript code block on teams without using developer tools @Subhasish-MSFT

Comment: This is currently not possible inside Teams